# Replacement of URLDecoder

Tags: java, decode, encode

Sorry, I edit question again to make it clearly.

If there is a filename called `abc你好+`.

When this filename pasre in Content-Disposition header as `abc%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD+`.

I decode `abc%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD+` through java.net.URLDecoder.decode() but it turned to be `abc你好`, the plus sign is replaced with space, thus the filename is not the original one.

I wonder if there is build-in method or other 3rd party package to decode and avoid plus pattern to be space. Because I just want to decode the string which had been percentage encoding. Thank you.

Comment: Spaces are perfectly valid in filenames on many platforms. Do you have a specific error?

Answer (score 3):

if you're talking about parsing the `Content-Disposition` header, which looks like this here for example:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file+name.txt";
```

then you don't need to decode what's written in the quotes using url encoding. What's inside the quotes is going to be the right filename without encoding necessary. Therefore, the plus represents an actual plus. If it were a space, the header would look like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file name.txt";
```

for some more theory behind this:

This [RFC 6266, section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4.1) specifies the Content-Disposition header with how the filename should be formatted. They losely mention that the filename is just "as is" and not encoded, but they also reference that details on the encoding can be found in[RFC 2616, Section 3.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6) that section however does not really detail out the specific encoding.

So my suggestion: assume the filename parameter is "right as is". That is unless you're expecting to deal with filenames that contain non-ascii characters. in which case, details can also be found in the two mentioned RFCs.

Answer (score -1):

`+` in a URL *means* space. If you want `+` to mean +, that's bizarre, and no tool exists to do that, because that's not what URL decoding means. Note that `+` and `%20` in a URL are identical and are both turned into a space, as per spec. If you want `+` to remain `+`, but `%20` to turn into space, you'd have to write your own URL decoder. If you don't care about `%20`, you can always take the string that the url decoder gives you, and call `.replace(" ", "+")` on it.

Comment: "+ and %20 in a URL are identical and are both turned into a space, as per spec" is wrong. This was only mentioned by RFC 1630, which was not a standard, but just an info summarizing some obsoleted non-standard use at that time. The actual spec (RFC 1738 and following) does not mention such replacement at all. RFC 3986 puts `+` to "reserved characters" (sub-delims). "characters in the reserved set are protected from normalization and are therefore safe to be used by scheme-specific and producer-specific algorithms for delimiting data subcomponents within a URI".